# pymysql and BEFORE INSERT trigger problem

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I have a DB table which looks like

```
CREATE TABLE `localquotes` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `createTime` timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  `tag` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `monthNum` int NOT NULL,
  `flag` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `optionType` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `symbol` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `bid` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `ask` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

for which one I have created a trigger

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`localhost` TRIGGER `localquotes_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `localquotes` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

SET new.tag=left(symbol,3);
SET new.monthNum=right(left(symbol,5),1);
SET new.optionType=left(right(symbol,11),1);
SET new.flag=right(left(symbol,11),4);

END
```

which is causing `pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'symbol' in 'field list'")` for pymysql on simple INSERT like

```
insertQuery = "INSERT INTO localquotes (tag,monthNum,flag,optionType,symbol,bid) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
insertValues = ('UNKNOWN', d.strftime("%m"), 0, 'X', symbol, bid)
cursor.execute(insertQuery, insertValues)
db.commit()
```

When I will remove that trigger insert works fine.

Any clue why code is complaining about `symbol` column, which exists, when there is trigger set for that column value from the insert request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must reference all the columns of the row that spawned the trigger with the `NEW.*` prefix.

```
SET new.tag=left(new.symbol,3);
```

And so on.

Comment: OK, so this is MySQL problem not the code then. Thanks!